# How to find azure redis cache total memory using redis commond

Tags: azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

I have started to learn Redis cache I had the plan to get total azure Redis cache memory through node js API call I have searched but I am not getting clear vision could you assist me how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create `Azure Redis Cache` on portal.**

**2. Click `Console`.**

[image]

**3. Input `info memory` command, and check the output info. I believe `maxmemory` is you want.**

[image]

**4. Test Code.**

```
    'use strict'

    var redis = require("redis");
    var bluebird = require("bluebird");

    const PORT=6380;
    const REDISCACHEHOSTNAME="jas***.windows.net";
    const REDISCACHEKEY="+tDRMmw********56ooVF7c=";

    // Convert Redis client API to use promises, to make it usable with async/await syntax
    bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
    bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

    async function testCache() {
        var cacheConnection = redis.createClient(PORT, REDISCACHEHOSTNAME, 
            {auth_pass: REDISCACHEKEY, tls: {servername: REDISCACHEHOSTNAME}});

        // Simple PING command
        console.log("\nCache command: info memory");
        let response=await cacheConnection.sendCommandAsync("info",["memory"]);
        let obj=parseInfo(response);
        console.log("Cache response : maxmemory = " + obj.maxmemory);
    }

    function parseInfo( info ) {
        var lines = info.split( "\r\n" );
        var obj = { };
        for ( var i = 0, l = info.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            var line = lines[ i ];
            if ( line && line.split ) {
                line = line.split( ":" );
                if ( line.length > 1 ) {
                    var key = line.shift( );
                    obj[ key ] = line.join( ":" );
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    testCache();
```

**5. Test Result.**

[image]